# How to list all available versions of a snap which is not installed?

Tags: snap, versions

How to list all available versions of a snap which is not installed?

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 with snap 2.39.3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use `snap find <app name>`

```
➜  ~ snap find vlc
Name            Version                 Publisher  Notes  Summary
vlc             3.0.7                   videolan*  -      The ultimate media player
dav1d           0.2.0-1-ge29cb9a        videolan*  -      AV1 decoder from VideoLAN
peerflix        v0.39.0+git1.df28e20    pmagill    -      Streaming torrent client for Node.js
mjpg-streamer   2.0                     ogra       -      UVC webcam streaming tool
audio-recorder  3.0.5+rev1432+pkg-7b07  brlin      -      A free audio-recorder for Linux (EXTREMELY BUGGY)
➜  ~
```

`snap info <app name>` for versions

```
➜  ~ snap info vlc
name:      vlc
summary:   The ultimate media player
publisher: VideoLAN*
contact:   https://www.videolan.org/support/
license:   GPL-2.0+
description: |
  VLC is the VideoLAN project's media player.

  Completely open source and privacy-friendly, it plays every multimedia file and streams.

  It notably plays MKV, MP4, MPEG, MPEG-2, MPEG-4, DivX, MOV, WMV, QuickTime, WebM, FLAC, MP3,
  Ogg/Vorbis files, BluRays, DVDs, VCDs, podcasts, and multimedia streams from various network
  sources. It supports subtitles, closed captions and is translated in numerous languages.
snap-id: RT9mcUhVsRYrDLG8qnvGiy26NKvv6Qkd
channels:
  stable:    3.0.7                      2019-06-07 (1049) 212MB -
  candidate: 3.0.7                      2019-06-07 (1049) 212MB -
  beta:      3.0.7.1-1-29-g2ed25c9      2019-07-14 (1105) 212MB -
  edge:      4.0.0-dev-8661-g5f26bfea1d 2019-07-14 (1104) 318MB -
➜  ~
```

Comment: I might be a little stupid here, but where does it list the available versions? Do you mean the channels? But what if I want to download previous versions?